# ¿Por qué no puedo crear el objeto dianaIzq (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, string, variables

Hola comunidad de StackOverflow,

El problema es que no me deja crear el objeto `dianaIzq`, ya que me dice que no encuentra la imagen. El segundo parámetro que recibe el constructor que crea el objeto es la URL.

Para armar la URL combino `strings` y una variable, que necesito que del tipo `string`. Esto es para poder ir cambiando la URL de la imagen.

Lo que no entiendo es por qué no puedo hacer esta combinación de strings y variable.

Muchas Gracias por su ayuda, aquí está el código:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>DAIGHT</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="DAIGHT.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas width="600" height="600" id="c"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        inicio();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var posDiana;

var Imagen = function(canvas, url, x, y) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.pos = {x, y};
    this.crearImagen(url);
}

Imagen.prototype.crearImagen = function(url) {
    var self = this;
    this.imagen = new Image();
    this.imagen.onload = function() {
        self.dibujar();
    };
    this.imagen.src = url;
}

Imagen.prototype.dibujar = function() {
    this.canvas.drawImage(this.imagen, this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
}

var teclas = [37, 38, 39, 40];

function inicio() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");

    var dinosaur = new Imagen(canvas, "Dinosaur.png", 400, 400);

    document.addEventListener("keydown", teclado);
    var dianaIzq = new Imagen(canvas, "diana-" + posDiana + ".png", 200, 200);
}

function teclado(lol)
{
    var tecla = lol.keyCode;

    //Flecha Izquierda
    if (tecla == teclas[0])
    {
        posDiana = "izq";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Claro que puedes hacer una combinación de cadenas y variables... ¡pero tienes que asegurarte de que la variable está instanciada! Ahora mismo estás haciendo:

```
var dianaIzq = new Imagen(canvas, "diana-" + posDiana + ".png", 200, 200);
```

en `inicio()`, pero cuando `inicio()` se llama, `posDiana` aún no tiene ningún valor porque, aunque se declara de manera global, no se inicializa hasta que se llame al método `teclaro()`. Entonces en lugar de intentar abrir la image "diana-izq.png", está intentando abrir la imagen "diana-undefined.png" que seguramente no existe y por eso no te funciona.